# ModelStateDictionary does not contain a definition for CopyTo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET Core RC 1 (full .NET Framework) works for me the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyProject.Classes.Filters.ModelState
{
    public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            if (controller != null)
            {
                var modelState = controller.ViewData.ModelState;
                if (modelState != null)
                {
                    var dictionary = new KeyValuePair<string, ModelStateEntry>[modelState.Count];
                    modelState.CopyTo(dictionary, 0);
                    var listError = dictionary.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));
                    controller.TempData["ModelState"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listError);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (full .NET Framework), an error occurs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyProject.Models.ModelState
{
    public class SetTempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            if (controller != null)
            {
                var modelState = controller.ViewData.ModelState;
                if (modelState != null)
                {
                    var dictionary = new KeyValuePair<string, ModelStateEntry>[modelState.Count];
                    modelState.CopyTo(dictionary, 0);
                    modelState = dictionary.[0];
                    var listError = dictionary.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));
                    controller.TempData["ModelState"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listError);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 'ModelStateDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo' and
>   no extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ModelStateDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Maybe I need to connect a new reference to an assembly that is not needed in ASP.NET Core RC 1?

Comment: Maybe adding `System.Web` could resolve the error.

Comment: @diiN_ No, the addition of `System.Web` did not solve the problem

Comment: Please don't use the `asp.net-mvc6` tag for ASP.NET Core MVC related questions to avoid confusion about a future ASP.NET MVC version. Also don't stuff tags into question titles

Comment: `ModelStateDictionary` does not implement `IDictionary<,>` hence does not have a `CopyTo` method on it. In your case, you could replace your code with `var listErrorr = modelState.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault(s => s != null));` and that should be functionally equivalent to what you were doing in the snippet.

Comment: @Pranav Thank you, it works. Please issue this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelStateDictionary` does not implement `IDictionary<,>` hence does not have a `CopyTo` method on it. In your case, you could replace your code with

```
var listErrorr = modelState.ToDictionary(
  m => m.Key, 
  m => m.Value.Errors
    .Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null)
);
```

and that should be functionally equivalent to what you were doing in the original snippet.